# How can I make my web application faster in Australia when it is hosted in USA

Tags: web-hosting, php, mysql

I have www.localo.org hosted on a BlueHost server in USA but I am in Australia and it is INCREDIBLY SLOW!

I uploaded it to a Crazy Domains server in Australia and it ran flawlessly.

I don't want to have a separate server in every country, so what do I need to do to make it based in USA but run smoothly in distant countries?

Answer (score 4):

To begin with, move static resources (images, css, js) to a server in Australia and keep the rest of your application in US. Since the majority of your webpage is going to be static resources, this is going to give you a significant improvement in response time.

If you can afford it, use a Content Delivery Network that has a presence in Australia. If you cannot afford one, use a regular hosting provider to host your files in Australia, and then switch between the two data centers using [Any cast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast). An ever cheaper solution is to determine the location based on ip address, and then use either http://us.mydomain.tld/image.jpg or http://au.mydomain.tld/image.jpg -- but this is obviously slower than the anycast DNS.

If the application is still slower, you will have to create a replica of your entire application in Australia, and that becomes a lot more expensive because you have to start replicating databases and deal with data synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably make your website faster by doing some general optimization. Here are some tips from Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Just glancing at your website, here is what I would recommend:

- it doesn't look like your PHP/HTML is being GZIPed, although your server can send GZIP content -- this will reduce your HTML that needs to be transfered by at least 50%, probably 75%
- move at least jQuery to Google's CDN, this will reduce a request that has to be made to your server; if you can, also move jQuery UI there
- move all of your JS includes to the bottom of the page so the page appears faster
- piwik is actually blocking the loading of the page; try to find a way to load it asynchronously
- consider as much of the inline JS to a separate file so it can be cached; this will also make your HTML smaller

Also, I'm in Canada and it takes just about a second to load the HTML alone. It looks like most of this is waiting for the server. So my recommendation is to find a faster server as I think most of the slowness you're finding is because of the server, although it could also be because of the way the site is coded (PHP).

Comment: There now is a way to load piwik asynchronously and is default from Piwik 1.11 and newer.